# Ошибка парсинга 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object..' при помощи Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Пытаюсь получить из Json Объект в обьекте получаю ошибку парсинга. Ошибка как то не информативная не понимаю что ему не по нраву.

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object
>   (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Inventory.Container[]' because the
>   type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Структура Json

```
{
"Data" : {
        "Id": 10,
        "Type": "тип10",
        "Name": "имя10",

        },
"Data" : {
        "Id": 11,
        "Type": "тип11",
        "Name": "Имя11",
        }
}
```

Код

```
Container[] data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Container[]>(json);



internal class Container
{
    [JsonProperty("Data")]
    public Data Value { get; set; }
    //С листом тоже ошибка
    //public List<Data> Value { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

И что делать если ключ `Data` будет другой? Можно как то без `[JsonProperty("Data")]` обойтись?

Comment: У вас же ошибка явно говорит, что ваш `JSON` не соответствует типу `Container[]`. Во первых, ваш JSON не валидный, точнее у вас два объекта data без массива и если вы их десериализуете, то получите всего 1 последний объект (можете проверить на [этом](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu) сайте. Во вторых, структура вашего json - это единичный объект, а вы пытаетесь его в массив засунуть. Для решения проблемы поменяйте `Container[]` на `Container`.

Comment: Теперь что касается ключей `Data` - если вы их не знаете и они разные, то вам надо использовать тип `Dictionary<string, Data>`, где Key - это будет ваш ключ `data`, а Value - будут ваши данные.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а как извлечь каждый `Data` в свой `Container`, что бы получить массив? Изменить структуру `Json`? При помощи `Dictionary`? Не совсем понял как его прикрутить сюда..

Comment: В текущем формате, не как, у вас ключи объектов одинаковые , если `Data` ключи будут разные, то я уже вам ответил, используйте Dictionary. Если они все же будут одинаковые, то значения 'Data' надо прятать, скажем внутрь объекта (что естественно требует переделки вашего JSON).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ изначально ключи не известны. Я сделал их одинаковыми тк как думал что он будет каждый новый ключ подходящий по наименованию заносить в новый `Container` и отсюда получится массив

Comment: Ну я вам сказал, по стандартам JSON - последующий дублирующий ключ будет заменять уже имеющийся. Как получить массив с "не известными" ключами, **но разными** - я уже писал, используйте `Dictionary<string, Data>`. Хотите текущий формат с уже имеющимися ключами десериализовать - пишите свой десериализатор, говорят это возможно (я не сталкивался), но я считаю это костылем...

Answer (score -2):

У вас все было почти верно, за исключением момента с именами у JObject. Так как имя объекта у вас будет неизвестно, используйте словарь, вроде вот так(с телефона):

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Data>>(json); 

public class Data
{
    [JsonProperty("Id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: С телефона уж лучше вовсе не писать, что бы не других в заблуждение не вводить. Ваш код выдаст NULL, дальше не поедет ([пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Oe5ESX)). Хотите написать ответ, можете взять мои комментарии и составить грамотный ответ (я не обижусь), но не проверенный код лучше и вовсе не писать.